# How do I make my object look smooth without using the subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, subdivision-surface

Sorry if I phrase this incorrectly but I was following a tutorial for a character model (the link should be below, end of part 4 and beginning of part 5) and I don't understand how he got the body to look so smooth. I tried applying the subdivision surface modifier but it only made my object look flatter, like this:[image]
It originally looks like this in sculpt mode: [image]
And like this in Object Mode:[image]
I want it to look smooth and not so blocky like in the tutorial: [image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdsY4BtlcpQ&list=PLvgIVNDU-Dxjb3eukDF5W0l0-6ShO9OiM&index=5

Thank you for your help

P.S.: Sorry if I added too many pictures to get my point across. Also, I am a novice at Blender, and yes, I know, even without the blockiness of my character's body, it doesn't look like the one in the tutorial. I'm doing my best so please disregard that if you can.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the effect you're seeing comes from switching the default Shade Flat (which uses a single Normal per face when shading, from what I can tell) to Shade Smooth (which interpolates -- that is, smoothly averages -- between the face normals to get useful normal information in between the basic face normals).

For example, here's an Icosphere with Shade Flat on by default:

[image]

And here's what happens with Shade Smooth turned on (in the sub-menu indicated in the above image):

[image]

Secondarily, you may also find it useful to use the Smooth Vertex (from the Vertex sub-menu in Edit Mode) transformation to improve the smoothness of the model. I believe Daniel Kreuter, the YouTuber who made the tutorial you're following (I recognize the mesh-work, having followed the same tutorial myself in the past), makes liberal use of Smooth Vertex; he explains this in one of the tutorial's earliest videos (and that he likes to hotkey it to the 'Q' key).